# nome do controller com hífen na url cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp, url, controller

Estou trabalhando SEO do google no meu site, e percebi, que nas separações entre palavras, um hífen é melhor do que um underline, ou palavras juntas, só que percebi que a princípio o cakephp não aceita que crie controllers desta forma `curso-no-exterior` só assim ou formas semelhantes `CursoNoExterior`, mas andei pesquisando e vi que em outros frameworks é possível fazer com que a url fique com hífen.
E eu quero saber se também é possível no cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration
Segundo a documentação do cakephp 2x, para montar um route para todas actions de um controller, é só fazer desta maneira. 
`Router::connect('/cooks/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users'));`
Desta forma, todas as actions que você tiver dentro do Controller, vão seguir o novo route que você criou.